# JPA ManyToMany to use grouping & crosswalks to join data together

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Building a Spring Boot REST service backed by MySQL here. I'm adding a super-simple chat feature to an app and this service will handle its backend/enndpoints. I'm new to JPA and have two concerns: (1) that my primordial data model itself may be a little awry; and (2) that I'm not wrapping that model correctly using JPA conventions/best practices.

So first: an overview of the simple problem I'm trying to solve: **Users** can send **Messages** to 1+ other Users. This creates a **Conversation**, which is really just a container of 1+ Messages. If the Conversation is only between 2 Users, it's considered (by the app) to be a *Direct Message (DM)*. Otherwise its considered to be a *Group Chat*.

My tables (pseudo-schema):

```
[users]
=======
id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INC INT NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

[conversations]
===============
id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INC INT NOT NULL,
created_on DATETIME NOT NULL

[messages]
==========
id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INC INT NOT NULL,
conversation_id FOREIGN KEY INT NOT NULL, # on conversations table
sender_id FOREIGN KEY INT NOT NULL, # on users table
text VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
sent_at DATETIME

[users_x_conversations]
=======================
id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INC INT NOT NULL,
conversation_id FOREIGN KEY INT NOT NULL, # on conversations table
user_id FOREIGN KEY INT NOT NULL, # on users table
```

So in my design above, you can see I'm really just using the `[conversations]` table as a placeholder and as a way of grouping messages to a single `conversation_id`, and then `[users_x_conversations]` is crosswalk (many-to-many) table where I'm actually storing *who* is a "member of" which conversation.

Is this the right approach to take or is there a better way to relate the tables here? That's Concern #1.

*Assumning* I'm modeling the problem at the database correctly, then I have the following JPA/entity classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}

@Entity(name = 'messages')
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = 'id', column=@Column(name='message_id'))
})
public class Message extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinColumn(name = 'conversation_id', referencedColumnName = 'conversation_id')
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Conversation conversation;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinColumn(name = 'user_id', referencedColumnName = 'user_id')
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private User sender;

    @Column(name = 'message_text')
    @NotEmpty
    private String text;

    @Column(name = 'message_sent_at')
    @NotNull
    private Date sentAt;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}

@Entity(name = 'conversations')
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = 'id', column=@Column(name='conversation_id'))
})
public class Conversation extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = 'conversation_created_on')
    @NotNull
    private Date createdOn;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}
```

What I'm stuck on now is: how should I model my `[users_x_conversations]` table at the JPA layer? Should I create something like this:

```
@Entity(name = 'users_x_conversations')
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = 'id', column=@Column(name='users_x_conversations_id'))
})
public class UserConversations extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinTable(
            name="users_x_conversations",
            joinColumns=[
                    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
            ],
            inverseJoinColumns=[
                    @JoinColumn(name="conversation_id")
            ]
    )
    private Map<User,Conversation> userConversations;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}
```

Basically my service will want to be able to do queries like:

- Given a `conversationId`, who are all the users that are members of that conversation?; and
- Given a `userId`, what are all the conversations that user is a member of (DM and Group Chat alike)?

Comment: you can implement `one-to-many` relationship between sender & receivers, if the no of receivers is one then its `direct` message, more than one is `1+`. querying would be simple with jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right approach to take or is there a better way to relate the tables here?

Your approach seems OK at the DB layer, except that if `users_x_conversations` serves *only* as a join table (*i.e.* if there are no extra properties associated with the (user, conversation) associations represented within), then I would use `(conversation_id, user_id)` as its PK instead of giving it a surrogate key.  If you don't do that, then you should at least put a uniqueness constraint on that pair.

> What I'm stuck on now is: how should I model my [users_x_conversations] table at the JPA layer?

I take you to be asking whether you should model that table *as an entity*.  If you insist on giving it a surrogate key as you have done, then that implies "yes".  But as I already discussed, I don't think that's needful.  Nor much useful, for that matter.  I would recommend instead modeling a direct many-to-many relationship between `Conversation` and `User` entities, with this table (less its `id` column) serving as the join table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "converations")
public class Conversation extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = 'conversation_created_on')
    @NotNull
    private Date createdOn;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "conversations")
    @JoinTable(name = "users_x_conversations",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="conversation_id", nullable = false, updateable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updateable = false)
    )
    private Set<User> users;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    // this is the non-owning side of the relationship; the join table mapping
    // is declared on the other side
    private Set<Conversation> conversations;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}
```

Note in that case that `User` and `Conversation` entities are *directly* associated in the object model.

---

On the other hand, if you *did* choose to model `users_x_conversations` via an entity of its own, then the code you present for it is all wrong.  It would look more like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_x_converations", uniqueConstraints =
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"converation_id", "user_id"}))
public class UserConversation extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    Conversation conversation;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    User user;

    // Ctors, getters & setters down here...
}
```

Note well that:

- This makes the object-level association between `Conversation`s and `User`s indirect, via `UserConversation` entities.  If the relationships are navigable from the other side, then they would be modelled via `@OneToMany` relationship fields of type `Set<UserConversation>` or `List<UserConversation>`.
- It requires more code, and more objects in the system at runtime.
- On the other hand, it does have the minor advantage of saving you from making a somewhat arbitrary choice of which side of a direct `@ManyToMany` relationship is the owning side.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing, amazing answer @John (+1). I think I'll go with you suggestion, to ditch the `UsersConversations` entity and just have the `@ManyToMany` between `User` and `Conversation`. The only part that I'm not fully understanding is the whole notion of deciding owning vs. non-owning "sides" of the many-to-many relationship. What are the benefits + limits of being the non-owning side (`User` in you example above)?Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb, the relationship is managed via the entities on the owning side.  That is, it is the state of the relationship field of the owning side of the relationship that is used to update the join table.

Comment: Thanks again @John (+1) So is it fair to say that in your example if I were to write `conversation.getUsers().add(new User(...))` that it **would** persist the new User to the `users_x_conversation` table (because Conversation is the "owner") but that if I wrote `user.getConversations().remove(i)` that it would only have the effect in memory (not in the DB), because Users is the non-owner? Am I understanding that correctly? Thanks again!

Comment: Also please note that your code example above throws `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: com.example.myapp.Conversation.users` exceptions.